# RxJava and Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rx-java

I'm trying to refactor my synchronization procedure with rxJava support. 
But I've faced a strange (for me) error.

Initially, I execute 'sync' procedure. Then in 'onCompleted' I execute syncPart2. It's the same procedure (but with others nodes to sync)

In the 'syncPart2' I get 'error=DatabaseError: Permission denied'. With database rules everything ok, this error appears on the different nodes (and current sync works fine).

Basically, I have 16 nodes to sync one by one, exactly in specific order. Maybe I've chosen wrong Rx operation to do that? By the way, if I use only one 'concat' everything ok! But I have more than 9 (max size of 'concat' args) nodes to sync.

```
public class RxFirebaseDatabase {

    @NonNull
    public static Observable<DataSnapshot> observeSingleValueEvent(@NonNull final Query query) {
        return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<DataSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void call(final Subscriber<? super DataSnapshot> subscriber) {
                query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
                            subscriber.onNext(dataSnapshot);
                            subscriber.onCompleted();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                        if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
                            subscriber.onError(new RxFirebaseDataException(error));
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

}




public static void sync() {

        Observable.concat(

                RxFirebaseDatabase.observeSingleValueEvent(getFirebaseReference(AppConstants.FIREBASE_CONSTANTS.DELETED_OBJECTS_NODE)),
                RxFirebaseDatabase.observeSingleValueEvent(getFirebaseReference(AppConstants.FIREBASE_CONSTANTS.MSI_NODE)),
                RxFirebaseDatabase.observeSingleValueEvent(getFirebaseReference(AppConstants.FIREBASE_CONSTANTS.COURSES_NODE)),
                RxFirebaseDatabase.observeSingleValueEvent(getFirebaseReference(AppConstants.FIREBASE_CONSTANTS.ALLERGIES_NODE)),
                RxFirebaseDatabase.observeSingleValueEvent(getFirebaseReference(AppConstants.FIREBASE_CONSTANTS.PHONES_NODE)),
                RxFirebaseDatabase.observeSingleValueEvent(getFirebaseReference(AppConstants.FIREBASE_CONSTANTS.MEDICINES_NODE)),
                RxFirebaseDatabase.observeSingleValueEvent(getFirebaseReference(AppConstants.FIREBASE_CONSTANTS.PROFILES_NODE)),
                RxFirebaseDatabase.observeSingleValueEvent(getFirebaseReference(AppConstants.FIREBASE_CONSTANTS.ANALYSES_NODE)),
                RxFirebaseDatabase.observeSingleValueEvent(getFirebaseReference(AppConstants.FIREBASE_CONSTANTS.DIAGNOSES_NODE))

        )
                .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<DataSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {

                        syncPart2();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {

                        Log.d(AppConstants.TAG_SYNC, "The error appears: " + e.getMessage());

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        GenericClass genericClass = retrieveInfoAboutNode(dataSnapshot);

                        if (genericClass.getMyType() == DeletedObject.class) {

                            handleDeletedObjects(dataSnapshot);

                        } else if (genericClass.getMyType() == MedicineSchedulerItem.class) {

                            handleMSI(dataSnapshot);

                        } else if (genericClass.getMyType() == MedicineCourse.class) {

                            handleMedicineCourse(dataSnapshot);

                        } else {

                            handle(dataSnapshot, genericClass);

                        }

                    }
                });
    }

    public static void syncPart2() {

        Observable.concat(
                RxFirebaseDatabase.observeSingleValueEvent(getFirebaseReference(AppConstants.FIREBASE_CONSTANTS.HOSPITALS_NODE)),
                RxFirebaseDatabase.observeSingleValueEvent(getFirebaseReference(AppConstants.FIREBASE_CONSTANTS.RECOMMENDATIONS_NODE)),
                RxFirebaseDatabase.observeSingleValueEvent(getFirebaseReference(AppConstants.FIREBASE_CONSTANTS.USER_FILES_NODE)),
                RxFirebaseDatabase.observeSingleValueEvent(getFirebaseReference(AppConstants.FIREBASE_CONSTANTS.SPECIALIZATIONS_NODE)),
                RxFirebaseDatabase.observeSingleValueEvent(getFirebaseReference(AppConstants.FIREBASE_CONSTANTS.DOCTORS_NODE)),
                RxFirebaseDatabase.observeSingleValueEvent(getFirebaseReference(AppConstants.FIREBASE_CONSTANTS.DOCTOR_VISITS_NODE)),
                RxFirebaseDatabase.observeSingleValueEvent(getFirebaseReference(AppConstants.FIREBASE_CONSTANTS.PHOTOS_NODE))
        )
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<DataSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {

                        EventBus.getDefault().post(new FirebaseEvents().new SyncFinished().new AllTasksFinished());

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {

                        Log.d(AppConstants.TAG_SYNC, "The error appears: " + e.getMessage());

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        GenericClass genericClass = retrieveInfoAboutNode(dataSnapshot);

                        handle(dataSnapshot, genericClass);

                    }
                });
    }
```

Comment: libs versions: com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.2 and io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.0

Comment: Make sure app name and client id are same as in firebase console.

Comment: I have no troubles if I use synchronization without rx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, permissions were not the cause of this issue.

I've had 'InvocationTargetException' because of Realm incorrect thread. But why the error was 'permissions denied' is still puzzle for me.